# Dynamically create a text file for download using Dart

Tags: dart, dart-html

How can we dynamically create a text file for download using Dart without involving the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has already been [asked and answered for JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3665115/1340742). Very similar solutions to those in that thread apply to Dart with very little modification. For example we could create an anchor element with a custom data URI and either present it to the user or call its `click` method:

```
String encodedFileContents = Uri.encodeComponent("Hello World!");

new AnchorElement(href: "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,$encodedFileContents")
  ..setAttribute("download", "file.txt")
  ..click();
```

See [DartPad example](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/9d80ba77bad1fff67c9bd5a80414d256) that allows the user to edit a table element's cells and then download the cell contents as a csv file.

Comment: How might this be done if you want to generate a very very large file? i.e. can we stream the file rather than store it all in memory?